# How to link a JSP ,servlet and a Java view bean?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to link a JSP ,servlet and a Java view bean?
I donot want to have any scriplet in JSP. How can i ask my JSP to invoke servlet to set the Implicit request and response objects and then display the properties from view bean on the jsp.

I need to pass request and response objects from jsp to servlet and then i want to display the properties defined in view bean to a JSP page.

JSP -> Servlet -> View Bean -> JSP

How to achieve this?

Comment: This is the 3rd question of `How ... JSP ,servlet and a Java view bean?` series. Please *rephrase* your question.

Comment: There are some similar [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984371)

Answer (score 4):

No need to pass *request* and *response* to the *bean/model* because your model classes are instantiated either in `JSPs` or `Servlets`.

You have to choose *servlet-centric* approach.

ViewBean.java

---

```
package in.abc.model;

public class Employee{
     private Integer id;
     private String  name;
     public Employee() { id=0; name="";}
     public Employee(Integer id, String name) { this.id=id; this.name=name;}
     public Integer getId()  { return id;}
     public String getName() { return name;}
     public void setId(Integer id) { this.id=id;}
     public void setName(String name) { this.name=name;}
}
```

ViewServlet.java

---

```
package in.abc.servlets;

@WebServlet(name = "ViewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/view"})
public class ViewServlet extends HttpServlet{
  public doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response) 
                 throws ServletException, IOException {

         //Instantiate the model 
         Employee emp=new Employee(10,"Mr.A");

         //Insert "model" object to request
         request.setAttribute("emp",emp);

         //forward the request to view.jsp
         request.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp").
                  forward(request,response);
  }

 public doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response) 
                 throws ServletException, IOException {

         //Instantiate the model 
         Employee emp=new Employee();

         //Read the request
         try{
             emp.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
         }catch(Exception ex) {}
         emp.setName(request.getParameter("name"));

         //Insert "model" object to request
         request.setAttribute("emp",emp);

         //forward the request to view.jsp
         request.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp").
                  forward(request,response);
  }
}
```

view.jsp

---

```
<h3>Employee info</h3>
<p>ID : ${emp.id}</p>
<p>Name : ${emp.name}</p>

<form method="post" action="view">
   <br/> <input type="text" name="id"/> 
   <br/> <input type="text" name="name"/>
   <br/> <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

index.jsp

---

```
<h1>
  <a href="view">View Employee details</a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But in servlet code, request.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp").
                  forward(request,response);
code is giving me the Cannot forward. Response already committed. error.
I am calling the servlet in the jsp by <jsp:include tag.
Please suggest.

Comment: @user1602657 - You have to *edit* your question and include code of .jsps and servlets.