# How to pass session value to java class

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a servlet which have these values and I want to pass these values to the java class in session attribute. How can I access these session attributes because I am not using JSF or Struts. This is simple Java Web application.

```
userID=map.get("UserID");

log.debug("The UserID in case of CCM authtication are : "+userID);

session.setAttribute("UserID", userID);
String refSys="";
refSys = map.get("refSystem");
log.debug("The refSystem in case of CCM authtication is: "+refSys);
session.setAttribute("refSystem", refSys);
```

This is how I am trying to get in the Java class and I am getting null in the Java class.

```
HttpSession session = null;

session.getAttribute("UserID");
```

Comment: You are setting session value to null so it throws the NullPointerException

Comment: Try to remove HttpSession session = null line

Comment: Could you share function signature snippet?

Comment: Here is the method in which i am trying to connect using public Map<String, String> socialMediaUserInfo(String tokenID).

Comment: replace first line of code with HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

Comment: Is it possible to get HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);  in non servlet class.

Comment: Please Refer This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866728/get-httpsessionrequest-from-simple-java-class-not-servlet-class

Answer (score -1):

Well, your session only can be null, because you don't initialize it. You have to do something like that first to initialize the `HttpSession`-object:

```
HttpSession s = request.getSession();
```

After that you can access your userId via the HttpSession.

Answer (score -1):

you are intially setting your session to null.

change ur code to this :

```
HttpSession session = null;
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String userId =session.getAttribute("UserID");
```

hope it works !!